# OnLocationChanged never gets called in a background location service. FusedlocationApi

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a tracker app and post the current location to my website along with the time and date in the background.
the problem is that the onlocationchanged function never gets called even though the same code works in foreground but not in a service.

MainActivity.java

```
package time.real.identify.location.tracker.gps.saksham.com.emptracker;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        startService(new Intent(this, TrackingService.class));
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS tracking enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[]
        grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST && grantResults.length == 1
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

TrackingService.java

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;


public class TrackingService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
    int i =0;
    double llo=0;
    double lla=0;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e("Loc","Connected");
  startLocationUpdates();
  Log.e("Loc","Started Location Updates!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.e("Loc","Connection suspended");

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e("Loc","Unable to connect");
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       Log.e("Loc","onLocationChanged");
       if(location!=null) {
           Log.e("Loc", "Latitude : " + location.getLatitude() + " , Longitude : " + location.getLongitude());
           double la = location.getLatitude();
           double lo = location.getLongitude();
           if (i == 1) {
               double da = la - lla;
               double d = lo - llo;
               if ((da > 0.0001 || da < -0.0001) || (d > 0.0001 || d < -0.0001)) {
                   lla = la;
                   llo = lo;
                   String l = la + "N," + lo + "E" + "/";
                   SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd,MM,yyyy");

                   SimpleDateFormat postFormaterTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh,mm,ss");

                   String newDateStr = postFormater.format(new Date().getTime());
                   String newTimeStr = postFormaterTime.format(new Date().getTime());
                   String link = "/*My website*/location=" + l + "&area=" + getarea(la, lo) + "&date=" + newDateStr + "&time=" + newTimeStr;
                   link = link.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

                   try {
                       URL url = new URL(link);
                   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                   HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                   try {
                       request.setURI(new URI(link));
                   } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   try {
                       client.execute(request);
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           } else if (i == 0) {
               String l = la + "N," + lo + "E" + "/";
               lla = la;
               llo = lo;
               SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd,MM,yyyy");

               SimpleDateFormat postFormaterTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH,mm,ss");

               String newDateStr = postFormater.format(new Date().getTime());
               String newTimeStr = postFormaterTime.format(new Date().getTime());
               String link = "/*MyWebsite*/location=" + l + "&area=" + getarea(la, lo) + "&date=" + newDateStr + "&time=" + newTimeStr;
               link = link.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

               try {
                   URL url = new URL(link);
               } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
               try {
                   request.setURI(new URI(link));
               } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               try {
                   client.execute(request);
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               i = 1;
           }
       }
    }
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable Permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
     mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);

        mLocationRequest.setExpirationDuration(15);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Location l = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (l != null) {
            String lon = String.valueOf(l.getLongitude());
            String lat = String.valueOf(l.getLatitude());
            Log.e("Loc", "Initial :- " + lon + "," + lat);
        }
    }
    public String getarea(double latitude,double longitude){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
//        String url = "https://geocode.xyz/"+latitude+","+longitude+"?geoit=xml"+"&auth=967851380791825982176x1596";
        String url = "https://geocode.xyz/"+latitude+","+longitude+"?geoit=xml";
        String area="",city="",country="";
        URL url1 = null;
        try {
            url1 = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        URLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = url1.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if((doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("staddress") == null) || (doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("state") == null) || (doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("country") == null)){
            return "Failed to get Location";
        }
        NodeList list = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("staddress");
        if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
            NodeList subList = list.item(0).getChildNodes();

            if (subList != null && subList.getLength() > 0) {
                area = subList.item(0).getNodeValue();
            }
        }
        list = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("state");
        if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
            NodeList subList = list.item(0).getChildNodes();

            if (subList != null && subList.getLength() > 0) {
                city = subList.item(0).getNodeValue();
            }
        }
        list = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("country");
        if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
            NodeList subList = list.item(0).getChildNodes();

            if (subList != null && subList.getLength() > 0) {
                country = subList.item(0).getNodeValue();
            }
        }
        String a = area + "," + city + "," + country;
        return a;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="time.real.identify.location.tracker.gps.saksham.com.emptracker">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<receiver android:name=".Start_on_Boot">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".TrackingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Start_on_Boot.java

```
package time.real.identify.location.tracker.gps.saksham.com.emptracker;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * Created by saksh on 25-03-2020.
 */

public class Start_on_Boot extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On modern android the user can choose to block location in the background.  Are you sure that isn't being set?

Comment: Make it a `ForegroundService` and instruct the users to whitelist your app in Android's battery saving settings. (You can neither force the whitelisting nor force showing that settings page if you plan to publish in Play Store. Except in rare cases where you manage to convince Google that it's really necessary.)

Comment: I am pretty sure it isn't blocked in background. When I go to running services, it shows that my service is still running and I have tried it on many phones with both battery management enabled and disabled.Even on emulators

Comment: Do you know any other solution?